# Emacs Org-Mode: Reset Line Indention Within org-indent-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I love Emacs and Org-Mode. But I can only stand to use Org Mode in the clean view (or whatever it's called - with org-indent-mode on).

My problem is that I often want to use headers that don't have a bullet in front of them. I want one asterisk to be the start of the list, not the header.

---

Example:

- List 1

  - List 2

Header 1

- List 3

  - List 4

---

But when I try to do this, Header 1 gets indented to the level of List 2.

I know just turning off org-indent-mode and getting used to that is one solution. **But is there a way to reset the indentation for Header 1?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you are talking about changing are pretty fundamental to org-mode; basically you are trying to change the org-mode syntax. The reason why **Header 1** in your example is not being dedented, is that org-mode does not see it as a headline, because headlines [by definition](http://orgmode.org/manual/Headlines.html) start with leading stars. Also, while it is *technically* supported to use `*` to identify a plain list item, this is not recommended, and can cause some unexpected behavior (see footnote 1 [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html#fn-1)).

That being said, you can have some control over the appearance of headlines. For example, you can use the [`org-bullets` package](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets). You can then define the bullets to use in place of `*` like this:

```
(setq org-bullets-bullet-list
'("◉" "◎" "⚫" "○" "►" "◇"))
```

which will define the bullets used for the first six levels of headlines. You can replace the bullets in that list with other utf-8 symbols, and you can even use `" "` as one of the symbols, so that your Headlines will be preceded by a single space. However, note that this only affects the way headlines are *displayed*; they will still be preceded by `*` in the actual file.

I know it is not very helpful, but my overall suggestion would be to stick with the org-mode syntax if you want to use org-mode, i.e., use a structure like this:

```
- List one
  - List two
* Header 1
  - List three
    - List four
```

with `*` starting a headline, and `-` starting a plain list. Since org-mode files are just plain text, the magic of that mode depends heavily on those files having a set structure. In my own experience, if you try to change that structure (another example is changing timestamp formats), it will cause more headaches than it relieves, and cause a lot of the functionality that makes org-mode so great to break.

Just as a side note: I prefer a cleaner view as well, and one option I like to enable in addition to `org-indent-mode` is `(setq org-hide-leading-stars t)`, which will display only a single star/bullet per headline (although the leading stars will still be present in the actual text file).